# Attempts to reopen a basic regex question

Tags: discussion, regex

A couple of days back I closed [a regex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852565/splitting-with-pipe-and-additional-spaces-around-this-symbol-if-any-using-separa) in [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29).  The question was basic, because the OP failed to escape the delimiter `|`.  So, I closed the question which was answered to one of the similar questions tagged with *separate* and `|` (*[R - separate with specific symbol, vertical bare, |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047726/r-separate-with-specific-symbol-vertical-bare)*).

Afterwards, I see a lot of drama on that post.  [The user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11329890/ryszard-czech) commented that it is not a duplicate because there is some space (`\\s*`) in there, so it is not exact duplicate, which is fine.  But, then it went to review and the consensus was to close.

Today, I find the same user, manipulating the post by adding some contents and then changing the post title.  I tried to roll back, but it was in vain because the person was very adamant in rolling back (at least 15 times) and then I gave up.  The reason they are editing is just to change the contents for reopening.  Is it allowed?

Another strange pattern is the same people are involved in duplicate linking to posts that have not much similarity and then deleting the posts.  This is going on forever and there are multiple posts showing the issue.

By checking Stack Overflow, there are [more than 30,000 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D%20%2B%20separate) with separate alone.

The original question title was *R regular expressions, separate column*.  Before submitting to review again for reopening, it was changed to *Splitting with pipe and additional spaces around this symbol if any using separate in R*. In addition, some content changes were made to show that it is not a dupe.  I am okay if the OP was doing this, but here the intention is different.

In addition, I would like to also mention that another post closed a couple of days back [was also reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69878997/revisions) by the same team. Are these reopenings only allowed for a certain group?

Based on the comments, the consensus seems to be that we need to duplicate only exact duplicates.  If that is the case [how is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69225773/how-to-include-percentage-and-numerator-denominator-in-the-same-cell) a duplicate.  It talks about sprintf, but if we use the format in the linked question, it is not exact.  My point is that there is a particular group which dupe tags and deletes posts in regex which are remotely connected and then reopens if any of their posts gets dupe linked.  The rollback itself shows the lengths to which they can go to reopen it.

Comment: First and foremost: There was absolutely no reason for 60+ rollbacks… _Maybe_ one or two edits then a mod flag would’ve probably been more productive.

Comment: @HenryEcker yes, the other person was very adamant.  So, I gave up afterwards and flagged it

Comment: The edit appears to be bringing up a warning that is produced by the solutions in the other threads. Why wouldn’t you just edit one of the answers to include how to handle the warning/extra whitespace? I agree we probably don’t need n threads addressing how to separate on delimiter, but if there are issues not addressed by the dupe targets wouldn’t it be more reasonable just to make the updates so the specific concern is addressed. _e.g._ “If there is whitespace around the delimiter use…”

Comment: @HenryEcker the edit is just by the person who wants to reopen it.  He changed the title as well

Comment: This is the [original version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69852565/1) leaving a link here since it's now 3 pages deep in revision history. What I am saying is that _if_ the dupe targets do not _currently_ address an issue that _is_ present in the current thread then it either (A) should not be a duplicate, or (B) the dupe targets should be updated to include how to handle whitespace. Because as it stands the original version does have extra whitespace around the delimiter `|` and the accepted answer _does_ address this in a way none of the dupe targets seem to...

Comment: @HenryEcker The OP didn't say specifically about that.  It is just a space character in regex and the warning is simple.  This is a very basic regex question.  Of course, it is difficult to get an exact dupe looking for space, then `|`.  But my point is that the same people will dupe tag it if it was someone else post

Comment: My question here is whether somebody (other than the OP) can change the contents just to reopen or not

Comment: *"My question here is whether somebody (other than the OP) can change the contents just to reopen or not"* ... this question is a bit vague. Of course a user can update/amend a question to explain why a dupe doesn't answer the question. I don't see why only the OP should be allowed to do that. Important is that the meaning of the question stays the same. Rewriting the question to be completely different isn't allowed for anybody.

Comment: @Tom The original question title was `R regular expressions, separate column` and the main issue was the escape of `|`.  The person changed the title before reviewing to `Splitting with pipe and additional spaces around this symbol if any using separate in R` which is very much different than the OP's intention

Comment: Regex again?! This is a cursed tag... akrun, *please* do not engage in prolonged rollback wars - an automatic moderator flag is raised after just a couple of edit rollbacks from the same user, there is no need to continue after making sure the author will not bulge, leave the decision to the exception handlers.

Comment: @OlegValter thanks.  This is the first time I was in a rollback war and I was surprised that people can be so adamant

Comment: It happens, but please do not do that in the future - there is literally a system in place to alert mods about such things happening, so as soon as you see this is going to happen, just disengage. Optionally raise a mod flag explaining why the decision should be made in your favor if it is not clear-cut - and leave the rest to mods: usually what follows is a roll back and/or comment (not always), and then a temporary post lock for cooldown if that is not sufficient.

Comment: why is it always regex

Comment: "In addition, I would like to also mention that another post closed couple of days back was also reopened by the same team" - no one involved in that question was involved in this one. Have you maybe considered that you need to review your closing strategy if several of your hammered questions get subsequently reopened?

Comment: And for the record, "yes, the other person was very adamant. So, I gave up afterwards and flagged it" -- that's not why you stop. You stop and flag early to avoid a rollback war, not because you give up. A few rollbacks are fine, but after that, you stop, not because you give up, but because it's a sign there's a conflict that needs a mod involved. If you can resolve it in the comments or in chat on your own, that's fine too, but you don't solve it by checking endurance in a rollback war.

Comment: @Zoe: There is also a (canonical) meta question about this somewhere. Though I can't locate it at this moment.

Comment: @Zoe  The party involved in the reopening is the same person who answered in both.  If somebody is suggesting is that editing should improve the clarity of the question, it is fine, but here based on the timing it is just to reopen it.  If they think that it is a genuine case for reopening, why not submit for reopen without any change.  I am ok with reopening a question if they don't find it `exact`.  But, then 90% of the questions dupe tagged and deleted by Wiktor is not exact as per the criteria.  If the mods are suggesting that editing is allowed, then this will be precedence for unethical

Comment: @Zoe Regarding the rollback, it is a mistake from my part.  I didn't know that somebody will go to this extent to rollback for just reopening

Answer (score 11):

If a question is closed as a duplicate anyone may edit to improve the clarity of the question. In the case that such edits resolve the closure reason the edit may also be used to add to reopen queue/cast a reopen vote. This may or may not be done by the OP. We're *not* trying to solve individuals' problems but as the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) states:

> we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.

From this directive, anyone can edit the question to make it clearer or more useful to future visitors. It does not matter who makes the edit to the question as long as it does not completely change the question<sup>1</sup>.

Furthermore, this type of edit is the specific guidance given by [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).

> Be sure that you've read the close notice and any comments on the question so you can address any concerns raised there. Addressing the concerns often means editing the post, [which any user may do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

This type of editing process is specifically *how* this type of disagreement is supposed to be resolved, and clarifies that it can be done by "any user."

I am not speaking to any "motives" only the fact that this kind of edit, to clarify *why* a duplicate does not apply, is part of the process.

---

In this *specific* circumstance, I can see the perspective that this question does consider whitespace around the `|`.

The [initial version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69852565/1) by [Felipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4109311/felipe) includes expected output:

> ```r
> output <-  tibble(B = c("Ae1 tt1", "Be1") , C = c("Ae2 tt2", "Be2"), D = c(NA, "Be3"))
> ```

There are no trailing spaces in the shown output.

It is also true that the answer in the linked thread produces:

> ```r
> input %>% separate(col=A, into=c("B","C","D"), sep = '\\|')
> # A tibble: 2 x 3   
>   B          C          D
>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
> 1 "Ae1 tt1 " " Ae2 tt2"  <NA>
> 2 "Be1 "     " Be2 "    " Be3"
> Warning message:
> Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [1].
> ```

Which was included in [Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69852565/2) by [Ryszard Czech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11329890/ryszard-czech).

From the points that (1) this is in line with the [official reopen guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), (2) it may be useful to have an answer which demonstrates separation with delimiter *and* whitespace and (3) that this edit only demonstrates that the existing answers do not *exactly* match the presented `output`, I do not believe the edit itself was problematic.

---

Having said this: the behaviour that followed *was* problematic. The continual assertion of specific edits was entirely unnecessary. At *most* 1 or 2 edits, then a moderator flag would have made significantly less impact on the post.

So, while I do *not* believe the edit alone is an issue, nor is necessarily the reopen vote, I also do not think that there needs to be a separate thread for handling whitespace around a delimiter.

If there already exists threads like [R - separate with specific symbol, vertical bare, | [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56047726/15497888) we do not need *another* entire thread dedicated to the letter `s` (`|` + `\\s*`). However, I believe the best approach would be to **edit** the **existing** answers to demonstrate how to handle whitespace around the delimiter.

We're supposed to make edits that make content more useful. "Splitting by delimiter" is a very common problem, but so too is "splitting by that delimiter and whitespace around that delimiter." Both of these go hand-in-hand. Such an addition to an existing answer would not be out of place, *and* make it an even stronger duplicate candidate in the future. Additionally, by updating answers to cover highly related topics it makes it harder to deny that a duplicate applies.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not entirely true as there are often cases where making large changes to questions to make them more generally useful is more helpful than any alternative.